# RoR on Heroku [Performance]: Threads, workers, whacamole, or dynos?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, heroku, puma

APP: Rails 4.2.9 on a Heroku standard-2x dyno.

DB: MySQL Heroku add-on ClearDB on Drift plan

Puma: workers 4, threads_count 1

No more than 10 people access this app each day. As far as their use goes, it's fine. No complaints on speed or downtime.

The app has lots of `.sum` and `.each { |n| total += n.value}` type things, which I suspect are the memory consuming things.

The problem is this app is going over the 1 GB Memory Usage everyday.

The price difference to the next dyno is just unreasonable for such a small operation. Also, it just seems crazy to pay 5x more, instead of making the app run better, considering the staff who uses it is **less than 10 people**!!

Anyways, as I read about this, I seem to become more and more uncertain. The question is:

What's the best way to lower Memory Usage in this kind of scenario? Which path should I focus on?

1. Change puma threads to more?
2. Change puma workers to more? (Less?)
3. Use the `whacamole` gem and just restart the dyno a few times a day?
4. Switch to 2 standard-1x dynos instead of one standard-2x?
5. Something else? Completely different?

**UPDATE** (Some PS output from development environment)

```
   CPU    MEM    TIME       BOSS
 -
   0.0    0.1    0:19.32    cluster worker 1: 58165
   0.0    0.4    0:39.90    cluster worker 0: 58165
   0.0    0.4    0:11.17    3.11.4 (tcp://localhost:3000) [finan]
 -
   0.0    0.1    0:19.32    cluster worker 1: 58165
   0.0    0.2    0:39.90    cluster worker 0: 58165
   0.0    0.4    0:11.17    3.11.4 (tcp://localhost:3000) [finan]
 -
   3.3    0.3    0:19.38    cluster worker 1: 58165
   0.3    0.2    0:39.90    cluster worker 0: 58165
   0.0    0.4    0:11.17    3.11.4 (tcp://localhost:3000) [finan]
 -
   25.7    2.1    0:19.94    cluster worker 1: 58165
   0.0    0.2    0:39.90    cluster worker 0: 58165
   0.0    0.4    0:11.17    3.11.4 (tcp://localhost:3000) [finan]
 -
   96.3    2.3    0:21.02    cluster worker 1: 58165
   0.0    0.2    0:39.90    cluster worker 0: 58165
   0.0    0.4    0:11.17    3.11.4 (tcp://localhost:3000) [finan]
 -
   96.7    2.4    0:22.09    cluster worker 1: 58165
   0.0    0.2    0:39.90    cluster worker 0: 58165
   0.0    0.4    0:11.17    3.11.4 (tcp://localhost:3000) [finan]
 -
   96.9    2.5    0:23.09    cluster worker 1: 58165
   0.1    0.4    0:11.18    3.11.4 (tcp://localhost:3000) [finan]
   0.0    0.2    0:39.90    cluster worker 0: 58165
 -
   97.5    2.6    0:24.15    cluster worker 1: 58165
   0.0    0.2    0:39.90    cluster worker 0: 58165
   0.0    0.4    0:11.18    3.11.4 (tcp://localhost:3000) [finan]
 -
   98.5    2.7    0:25.23    cluster worker 1: 58165
   0.0    0.2    0:39.90    cluster worker 0: 58165
   0.0    0.4    0:11.18    3.11.4 (tcp://localhost:3000) [finan]
 -
   98.2    2.8    0:26.32    cluster worker 1: 58165
   0.0    0.2    0:39.90    cluster worker 0: 58165
   0.0    0.4    0:11.18    3.11.4 (tcp://localhost:3000) [finan]
 -
   90.1    2.8    0:27.35    cluster worker 1: 58165
   0.0    0.2    0:39.90    cluster worker 0: 58165
   0.0    0.4    0:11.18    3.11.4 (tcp://localhost:3000) [finan]
 -
   97.9    2.9    0:28.42    cluster worker 1: 58165
   0.0    0.2    0:39.90    cluster worker 0: 58165
   0.0    0.4    0:11.18    3.11.4 (tcp://localhost:3000) [finan]
 -
   85.4    3.2    0:29.43    cluster worker 1: 58165
   0.0    0.2    0:39.90    cluster worker 0: 58165
   0.0    0.4    0:11.18    3.11.4 (tcp://localhost:3000) [finan]
 -
   91.7    4.9    0:30.42    cluster worker 1: 58165
   0.0    0.2    0:39.90    cluster worker 0: 58165
   0.0    0.2    0:11.18    3.11.4 (tcp://localhost:3000) [finan]
 -
   18.4    4.1    0:31.06    cluster worker 1: 58165
   0.0    0.1    0:39.90    cluster worker 0: 58165
   0.0    0.2    0:11.18    3.11.4 (tcp://localhost:3000) [finan]
 -
   0.2    3.5    0:31.06    cluster worker 1: 58165
   0.0    0.1    0:39.90    cluster worker 0: 58165
   0.0    0.2    0:11.18    3.11.4 (tcp://localhost:3000) [finan]
 -
   11.7    3.7    0:31.20    cluster worker 1: 58165
   2.5    0.4    0:39.94    cluster worker 0: 58165
   0.0    0.2    0:11.18    3.11.4 (tcp://localhost:3000) [finan]
 -
   0.1    3.7    0:31.20    cluster worker 1: 58165
   0.0    0.4    0:39.94    cluster worker 0: 58165
   0.0    0.2    0:11.18    3.11.4 (tcp://localhost:3000) [finan]
 -
   0.0    3.5    0:31.20    cluster worker 1: 58165
   0.0    0.4    0:39.94    cluster worker 0: 58165
   0.0    0.2    0:11.18    3.11.4 (tcp://localhost:3000) [finan]
 -
   0.4    0.2    0:11.18    3.11.4 (tcp://localhost:3000) [finan]
   0.0    3.4    0:31.20    cluster worker 1: 58165
   0.0    0.4    0:39.94    cluster worker 0: 58165
```

Comment: If you have no option to (get away from Heroku and/or profile your app memory usage), you can try 2x4(workers x threads) for the start. Then increase threads count up to 16 if no memory issues, OR fall back to 1x4(and try again to increase threads count) when 2x4 doesn't fit.

Comment: I've just added some PS output from development (my computer). Can you help me understand if `97.5` for CPU means that ONE worker is taking over the CPU? If that's the case, I should not have more than one?

Comment: CPU load is another issue. Typical web app should not load CPU at ~100%

Comment: Thank you! After looking at a lot of things yesterday, it seems like the current dyno with only 2 workers will be best. So far, so good. It seems like Heroku dynos are more CPU than RAM, so using CPU is ok, but loading up on RAM is the problem.

Comment: You are 146% right: Heroku is much more CPU than RAM. And it's very strange, as modern web app are "vice versa". And keep in mind the [unreal] price. That is why I never used Heroku for the production/staging. Quick demo presentation is only an option.

Comment: Haha Good to know. What's your go-to for production?

Comment: Amazon and DigitalOcean mainly. Sometimes it's regional cloud providers (when "very region specific" project).